# Некорректная работа synchronized java

Tags: java, synchronized

Изучаю Герберта Шилдта Java 8 Руководство для начинающих, и вопрос в следующем. Согласно книге метод synchronized обязан дать выполниться методу до завершения потока, а уже после запускать второй поток, что бы не было ошибок. Программа, просто находит сумму элементов массива.

```
public class SumArray {
    private int sum;

    synchronized int SumArray (int[] arr){
        sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sum += arr[i];

            System.out.println("Сумма "+ Thread.currentThread().getName() + " "+ sum);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }catch (InterruptedException exc){
                System.out.println("Ошибочка");
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
}

public class MyThread implements Runnable {
    Thread thrd;
    static SumArray sa = new SumArray();
    int a[];
    int answer;

    MyThread(String name, int[] arr){
        thrd = new Thread(this, name);
        a = arr;
        thrd.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int sum;

        System.out.println(thrd.getName() + "Запуск");
        answer = sa.SumArray(a);
        System.out.println("Сумма для " + thrd.getName()+" = " + answer);
        System.out.println(thrd.getName() + "Завершение");
        System.out.println("==================");

    }
}

class Sunc{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

        MyThread mt1 = new MyThread("Поток 1 ", a);
        MyThread mt2 = new MyThread("Поток 2 ", a);
    }
}
```

Результат должен быть похожим на это
[image: Ожидаемый результат]

Как видим, запускаются два потока, но сначала выполняется один, потом второй, у меня результат другой, в конце выполнения первого потока запускается второй.

[image: Полученный результат]

Может я в чем-то не разобрался, или какая-то неточность в книге, возможно в переводе. Почему один из потоков вмешивается в выполнение другого.

Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: Кто куда вмешивается? Потоки работают параллельно. Запуск цикла во втором потоке пошёл, как только первый вышел из синхронайзд блока. У вас в `synchronized` только метод `SumArray`, т.е, гарантированно последовательно будет вызван цикл `for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)`. У всего остального порядок не гарантирован.

`Thread.sleep(100)` тут, скорей всего, кроме переключение контекста ничего не делает. У вас поток всё ещё лочит весь `synchronized` блок. В итоге, цикл во втором потоке пошёл, как только первый вышел из синхронайзд блока.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потоки работают параллельно. Запуск цикла во втором потоке пошёл, как только первый вышел из синхронайзд блока.

У вас в `synchronized` только метод `SumArray`, т.е, гарантированно последовательно будет вызван цикл:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
```

У всего остального порядок не гарантирован.

`Thread.sleep(100)` тут, скорей всего, кроме переключение контекста ничего не делает. У вас поток всё ещё лочит весь `synchronized` блок. В итоге, цикл во втором потоке пошёл, как только первый вышел из синхронайзд блока.